# passing numpy ndarray as inputs of a fsolve function

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods

I want to numerically solve a system of nonlinear equations and pass numpy ndarrays as inputs. Consider the arbitrary code below:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def eqs(A, B, C, D):
    eq1 = (A - B * np.sin(C)).tolist()
    eq2 = [5 * B + D * np.sum(A * np.cos(C))]
    return eq1 + eq2

n = 3

A = np.zeros((n))
A0 = np.random.rand(n)
B = 0.0
B0 = np.random.rand(1)[0]

C = np.random.rand(n)
D =  np.random.rand(1)[0]

sol = fsolve(func = eqs, x0 = [A0, B0], args = [C, D])
```

which leads to

> missing required positional arguments

error and changing the function to:

```py
def eqs(A, B, C, D):
    eq1 = A - B * np.sin(C)
    eq2 = C[0] * B + D * np.sum(A * np.cos(C))
    return [eq1, eq2]
```

also doesn't help. However, I highly doubt that the error has anything to do with passing ndarrays. One approach could be to change all the ndarrays to python lists back and forth. But then I would not be able to use numpy's vectorized functions like `np.sin()`...

I would appreciate if you could help me know how this should be done.

**P.S.** Equations above are just arbitrary and they may not have solutions at all.

Comment: can you post this non linear equations that you try to solve?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi mind if I share them in private? got Twitter?

Comment: i don't use any social accounts

Comment: email? any other way I can share the code privately? the code I'm working on is for non-published research and I can't share it publicly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this solve your equation:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def eqs(X, Y):
    A, B = X[:3], X[3]
    C, D = Y[:3], Y[3]
    eq1 = A - B * np.sin(C)
    eq2 = C[0] * B + D * np.sum(A * np.cos(C))
    return np.append(eq1, eq2)

n = 3

A = np.zeros((n))
A0 = np.random.rand(n)
B = 0.0
B0 = np.random.rand(1)[0]

C = np.random.rand(n)
D =  np.random.rand(1)[0]

sol = fsolve(func = eqs, x0 = np.append(A0, B0), args = np.append(C, D))
sol
```

Output:

```
array([ 0.e+000, -1.e-323,  5.e-324, -1.e-323])
```

Comment: but then how do you pass D and C? I want them to be passed because they are not necessarily constants as shown in the arbitrary code.

Answer (score 1):

These `scipy.optimize` functions require a function with a signature like

```
f(x, *args)
```

`x` is a array (often 1d) that the solver will vary; `args` is a tuple of arguments that are just passed through from the outside.

Change your `eqs` to fit this pattern

```
In [11]: def eqs(X, C, D): 
    ...:     A, B  = X[:-1], X[-1] 
    ...:     eq1 = (A - B * np.sin(C)).tolist() 
    ...:     eq2 = [5 * B + D * np.sum(A * np.cos(C))] 
    ...:     return eq1 + eq2 

    ...: n = 3 
    ...: A0 = np.random.rand(n) 
    ...: B0 = np.random.rand(1) 
    ...:  
    ...: C = np.random.rand(n) 
    ...: D =  np.random.rand(1)
```

Make a test call to `eqs`:

```
In [12]: eqs(np.concatenate((A0,B0)),C,D)                                                            
Out[12]: 
[-0.28460532658572657,
 -0.03649115738682615,
 0.7625781482352719,
 array([5.46430853])]
```

Now try it in the `fsolve`:

```
In [13]: fsolve(eqs, np.concatenate((A0,B0)), args=(C,D))                                            
Out[13]: array([0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

Comment: thanks a lot. How is this is compared to the other solution? is this one better?