# Faster method to numerously solve for multiple parameters governed by multiple nonlinear equations with multiple variable arguments?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy-optimize

I am looking for a tweak that I could apply to the code shown later or an alternate method that would lead to faster run time. In general, I want to find the values of two parameters that are governed by a set of multiple nonlinear equations. These equations use multiple variable arguments.

An Example of the problem at hand is presented for only a small array (4 values) as an example:

- I want to find the values of q and h that are governed by 2 non-linear equations
- I will need to apply this procedure to larger a and b arrays each of about 50k values

*Equations are:*

- q = k/2L * (h^2 - b^2)
- q = -2 * pi * k * (h-a) / ln((h-d)/r)

arguments/variables:

- k = 144.0
- L = 550.0
- d = 140.9
- r = 0.5
- a = [190.0, 185.0, 160.0, 150.0]
- b = [70.0, 70.0, 30.0, 10.0]

I followed suggestions in similar posts at stackoverflow, mostly [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56787038/passing-numpy-ndarray-as-inputs-of-a-fsolve-function), and modified my original code to avoid using a for loop. Though, after doing that, I tried applying the code to a big array of variables, but it took quite some time.

I should also mention that I am only interested in the solution when h is between a certain limit (when h is greater than d+r and less than 300), but I didn't know how to apply this in fsolve when I am solving for multiple parameters and using multiple non-linear functions.

The final code that I am currently using is shown in this post, but I am looking for something that is faster and more efficient.

```
import numpy as np

from scipy import optimize

def functions(X, Y):

    q,h = np.split(X,2)

    a,b = np.split(Y[:-4],2)

    k,L = Y[-4],Y[-3]

    d,r = Y[-2],Y[-1]

    f1 = q - k/(2.0*L)*(h**2 - b**2) 

    f2 = q + 2.0*np.pi*k*(h - a)/ np.log((h - d)/r)

    return np.append(f1, f2)

k = 144.0

L = 550.0

d = 140.9

r = 0.5

a_vals = np.array([190.0, 185.0, 160.0, 150.0])

b_vals = np.array([70.0, 70.0, 30.0, 10.0])

q0 = np.array([4059.5, 3814.7, 3212.5, 2912.7]) #initial guesses for q

h0 = np.array([189.5, 184.5, 159.5, 149.5]) #initial guesses for h

my_args = np.concatenate((a_vals, b_vals, k, L, d, r), axis=None)

initial_guesses = np.concatenate((q0, h0), axis=None)

qs,hs = np.split(optimize.fsolve(func = functions, x0 = initial_guesses, args= my_args), 2)
```

Comment: In order to find a specific solution that satisfies some of your bounds and constraints, you could use `scipy.optimize.minimize` similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67034006/solve-equation-using-fsolve-with-inequality-equations/67034757#67034757). You only need to add an additional constraint to ensure `d+r <= 300`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution in your case is to use the **Numba's JIT** since many (short) calls to the same function are performed. Here is an example:

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('float64[::1](float64[::1],float64[::1])')
def functions(X, Y):
    q,h = np.split(X,2)
    a,b = np.split(Y[:-4],2)
    k,L = Y[-4],Y[-3]
    d,r = Y[-2],Y[-1]
    f1 = q - k/(2.0*L)*(h**2 - b**2) 
    f2 = q + 2.0*np.pi*k*(h - a)/ np.log((h - d)/r)
    return np.append(f1, f2)

# ... (the rest is the same)
```

This is **12 times faster** on my machine.

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply and help. I tried the code you suggested but I received a TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Use of unsupported NumPy function 'numpy.split' or unsupported use of the function.  I modified the np.split to normal slicing and it worked and it was about 9 times faster which is way better, so thanks to you. I just have a question, is this decoration method the same as @numba.vectorize? can the @numba.vectorize be used in this case?

Comment: @yousef I guess the `np.split` is due to a not up to date version of Numba. It was working for me with Numba 0.53.1. AFAIK, `@numba.vectorize` is different: it works per item (the computation of each item is independent of the others). So `@numba.njit` is more general as you can perform reduction, shuffles, etc. with it (note that `@numba.njit` is equivalent to the most general version `@numba.jit` with the parameter `nopython=True`). I do not think `@numba.vectorize` can be used in this case.